# my android project dependence the httpclient and httpMime can't build

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm use the dependencies by

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'`
```

then  build it there is error
    Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':XmppDemo:packageDebug'.

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
>       File 1: E:\develop\gradle.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient-android\4.3.5\82edcaec6c7b4599eaeaaf11167ceea41db42f33\httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar
>       File 2: E:\develop\gradle.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient-android\4.3.5\82edcaec6c7b4599eaeaaf11167ceea41db42f33\httpclient-android-4.3.5.jar

can you help me explain the reason.
excuse me! i'm Chinese,my English is not good.

Comment: Error:Gradle: duplicate files during packaging of APK E:\workspace\android\XmppDemo\build\outputs\apk\XmppDemo-debug-unaligned.apk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The packager is telling you that the file META-INF/NOTICE appears in more than one jar file (which creates a conflict) and therefore cannot be included. To solve that problem, add this section to your `build.gradle` (you might already have an `android` closure, in which case add just the `packagingOptions` part):

```
android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
 }
}
```

Your particular problem is about the `NOTICE` file but I suspect that you might also run into problems with `LICENSE` and `DEPENDENCIES`.